# Problems with group_by statement, sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with the following query; This, itself, works fine, but it groups by second, I want to truncate seconds and group by minute. I have experimented with date_trunc, extract and so on, but I haven't had any luck. When the engine was sqlite, extract('minute') worked fine, but not with postgresql.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 8.1.23 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

```
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('date', TIMESTAMP),
        Column('src', String),
        Column('dst', String),
        Column('len', String),
        Column('sport', String),
        Column('dport', String),
        Column('method', String),
        Column('host', String),
        Column('useragent', String),
        Column('statusline', String),
        Column('location', String),
        Column('server', String),
        Column('load', String),

now = datetime.datetime.now()                
DD = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)    
DD = DD.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')        
query = session.query(HTTP.date,HTTP.statusline, func.count(HTTP.statusline).                                                                           
                label('count')).filter(HTTP.statusline.like('%'+status+'%'), HTTP.date>=(DD)).group_by(HTTP.date, HTTP.statusline).order_by(asc(HTTP.date)).all()
```

Comment: You forgot to provide your table definition and your postgres version number.

Comment: Who is asking this question? ohpaulsen or user2255212?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ohpaulsen told me that they're working together, but he doesn't have the comment privileges.

Comment: @TimSæterøy: I see, thanks. FYI: `Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.` [More info here.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you do *anything* else, consider upgrading to a current version of [**PostgreSQL 8.1** is long dead and forgotten](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Not entirely sure about the notation, but with updates from [@Audrius in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866273/problems-with-group-by-statement-sqlalchemy-and-postgresql/15866538?noredirect=1#comment22585406_15866538) it should work like this:

```
query = session.query(
       date_trunc('min', http.date).label('date_minute')
      ,http.statusline
      ,func.count(http.statusline).label('count')
   ).filter(http.statusline.contains(status)
           ,http.date>=(DD)
   ).group_by('date_minute'
             ,http.statusline
   ).order_by(asc('date_minute')).all()
```

Basically, use `date_trunc('min', http.date)` instead of `http.date` in `SELECT` and the alias in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

BTW: I find it very misleading to use `date` as name for a `timestamp`. Aside from that, my advice is *never* to use any of the base type names as identifiers. Leads to very confusing error messages and other errors hard to debug.

Comment: `'%'+status+'%'` is fine, SQLAlchemy will do the right thing when emitting actual SQL, although in this case [`.contains(status)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.contains) would look cleaner. Also in `.group_by()` and `.order_by()` values from `.label()` can be used, e.g. `.group_by('date_minute', http.statusline)`.